Where does the term "Predicate Pushdown" originate from?
I keep reading all sources about predicate pushdown and how it works,
but I'm struggling to piece together where this term originated from.
So far, I understand that "Predicate" stems from the use of clauses in SQL,
but "pushdown" seems, if anything, to have just been a slang applied to the idea of "pushing the predicate" up in a scan?
I hardly understand how to naturally form the kind of sentence I had to just put together when explaining why "pushdown" is used, here.
So where does this term really come from? Any idea on the who/where/when around coining this term? Is it originally a SQL term, like everything seems to imply?

I don't think anyone could give you a straight answer. It does seem to be some sort of industry term, but this is more of a history question than anything else.

A predicate, here, is a filter predicate in a WHERE condition. Predicate pushdown happens when the SQL engine reads from external data sources, for example , Parquet, the predicate is along an existing Parquet partitioning scheme, and the external data retrieval framework is clever enough to just read the concerned files instead of going into full table scan, only to discard the majority of the rows once they reach the query engine. It's not an industrial jargon - it's the concept of moving selective criteria as close to the source as possible to avoid unnecessary data movement.
